# Simple Java: How to make string replace and wait then replace again?

Tags: java, string, applet

I am making something and there will be a "Calculating" page on Java on an Applet! so what i want it to do is first drawstring and display "Calculating." then after a second it replaces that string and says "Calculating.." then again replace that string with "Calculating..." and loop that about 5 times. Is there any simple way of doing this??

I want it to display it on the applet!

Comment: You either want to use a Swing `Timer` or `SwingWorker`. See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details.  How, and wanting to display it on a applet is not a constraint

Comment: first of all, if you're replacing the String in a loop, dont use String as it creates a new String and that is not a good practice. use StringBuilder/Buffer instead.  next to replace your value in the applet, use Javascript/Ajax. example: http://www.mkyong.com/applet/how-to-javascript-access-applet-method/

Answer (score 2):

You either want to use a Swing `Timer` or `SwingWorker`. See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details.

For example...

[image: Calc]

```
  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.EventQueue;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.Timer;
  import javax.swing.UIManager;
  import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

  public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }

          JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.add(new TestPane());
          frame.pack();
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);
        }
      });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

      private JLabel label;
      private static final String DOTS = "...";
      private static final String TEXT = "Calculating";
      private int counter;

      public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        label = new JLabel(getText());
        add(label);

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            counter++;
            if (counter > 3) {
              counter = 0;
            }
            label.setText(getText());
          }
        });
        timer.start();
      }

      protected String getText() {

        String sufix = DOTS.substring(0, counter);
        sufix = String.format("%-3s", sufix);

        return TEXT + sufix;

      }

      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
      }

    }

  }
```

Adding this to an applet is about as easy as adding to a `JFrame`

Comment: How would i covert that to an Applet?

Comment: You don't, you add the panel to the applet - that's the point